# How to get not exists set in collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanna to be get a set that doesn't exists in collection. like following:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5] # 2,3,4 is not exists
User.where(:id => ids)
```

I want to get a set [2,3,4]

Without affecting performance,Have a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
ids - User.where(id: ids).select(:id).map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 3.2 there's [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck), it returns a single column's values:

```
User.pluck(:id)
# => [1,5,6,7,...] # all user ids
```

Or, in your case:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5] # 2,3,4 do not exist
ids - User.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)
# => [1,5]
```